# finding expected value from cdf function

Tags: statistics

$F(x)=1-x^{-a}$   for $x\ge1$

find E(x) for those values of a for which E(x) exists.

My approach:

alpha must be positive since $F(\infty)$ must equal 1.

differentiate F(x) to get:
$f(x)=ax^{-a-1}$

$E(x)=\int_1^\infty xax^{-a-1}$
$=a\int_1^\infty x^{-a}$

after evaluating that integral and subbing in the limits you can see that a can't be 0 or 1 so finally,

$E(x)=\frac{a}{a-1}$

Is this correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Actualy, for $a=0$ we have $E(x)=0$, which makes sense, since $P(x=0)=1$. The rest is correct.

Comment: Ah yes I see that now, I forgot about the a out the front.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. For $a=0$ we would have $F(x)=0, \forall x$, which is not possible. So we must have $a>1$ for the integral to converge and $E(x)$ exist.